# Read public key other than authorized_keys

Tags: linux

Does server capable to read public key other than default `authorized_keys`? I have a linux based server managed with more than one admin. One of them have resigned from the company. I'm having a thought that he may have added something like backdoor access. Just to be sure if this possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While to some extent you have to trust people, if you do not trust this person you can activate a security incident response plan. Take a comprehensive approach as suggested in the canonical question regarding [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/241174)

From the [sshd manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) note that the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive can change the file for user's public keys for auth. Just looking at this is **not sufficient** on a compromised host, as they can just as easily run a different hidden sshd or other malware.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if someone is knowledgeable and unscrupulous, and has had full access to a machine, you can't completely guarantee that the machine isn't compromised.

That said, if you just want to check for a couple of simple things related to your question:

1. Check the sshd config (likely `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`),  to see if it contains multiple values for `AuthorizedKeysFile`.
2. If you still have the user's original `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, grep the other home directories for the same key values to confirm they didn't simply append their key to that of another user account with administrative access to the server.
3. Run `visudo`, and also check your `/etc/passwd` to search for unexpected privileges and user accounts.